# R package checking - 'no such vignette' error

Tags: r, devtools

I am using devtools in R to develop an R package, following Hadley Wickham's excellent website. I have now come to the checking step, using devtools::check(). I pass through the checks up until 'checking running R code from vignettes', when I obtain the following error:

```
'smcfcs-vignette.Rmd' using 'UTF-8' ... failed
ERROR
Errors in running code in vignettes:
when running code in 'smcfcs-vignette.Rmd'
  ...

  When running vignette 'smcfcs-vignette.Rmd':
Error: No such vignette 'smcfcs-vignette.Rmd'
Execution halted

Error: Command failed (1)
```

I have written a vignette, which is called smcfcs-vignette.Rmd, and is stored in a vignettes sub-folder, and which I have developed using Markdown and Knitr. If I click Knit in RStudio, the vignette compiles and displays successfullly, yet I receive the above error when running devtools::check(). I have tried deleting everything apart from the first paragraph of text in the vignette, and the error still occurs. I therefore don't think it's to do with the content of the vignette file. It rather seems that devtools::check() is looking in the wrong folder for the vignette.

If anyone can shed any light on the source of my error, I'd be very grateful. If it helps, the package is on Github: https://github.com/jwb133/smcfcs

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R CMD CHECK`, and, in this instance `devtools::check()` by extensions, don't build things, they just check them. It's true that `devtools::check` has the `document` argument to re-roxygenize your package before checking, but it doesn't touch vignettes. So, you need to build your vignettes first. This is easily done with `devtools::build_vignettes()`.